# ActiveRecord Deadlock In Worker with Rails, MySql, Sidekiq and a Mutex

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In the demo below, `Admin.count` takes more than 10 seconds to execute. Weird, right?

I am using Sidekiq, a queue service built on Redis, [redis mutex](https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex), a tool to make sure that code is only executed by a single process at a time, and Ruby on Rails with a MySQL database.

The issue does not appear to be with RedisMutex, because `sleep(1)` works perfectly.

Our queue has a concurrency of five, so five jobs run at the same time.

```
class ConcurrencyTester
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    # If the worker hangs perpetually, stop it with an error.
    Timeout::timeout(10) {
      # Make sure only one process runs this block of code at a time. Wait up
      # to 10 seconds for other processes to finish
      mutex = RedisMutex.new('ConcurrencyTester', block: 10, expire: 50)
      mutex.with_lock do
        logger.info('starting task')
        logger.info(Admin.count) # hangs forever
        # sleep(1) # works
        logger.info('finishing task')
      end
    }
  end

  def test
    5.times do
      ConcurrencyTester.perform_async
    end
  end
end
```

I queue up the workers with `ConcurrencyTester.new.test`. After ten seconds, all fail due to the timeout:

```
2017-10-16T19:03:13.265Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyook ConcurrencyTester JID-bfd999897d7387cd01b909c0 INFO: start
2017-10-16T19:03:13.265Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyoig ConcurrencyTester JID-1ce4940b3400bb98a9be726f INFO: start
2017-10-16T19:03:13.266Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyouo ConcurrencyTester JID-03b860c995c6040d2de18707 INFO: start
2017-10-16T19:03:13.267Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyp0s ConcurrencyTester JID-d313f82c66f973caaaaf5ea6 INFO: start
2017-10-16T19:03:13.270Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyp6w ConcurrencyTester JID-e057dd6c641e9240250ca40a INFO: start
2017-10-16T19:03:13.271Z 54312 TID-ov67uwen8 ConcurrencyTester JID-bfd999897d7387cd01b909c0 INFO: starting task
2017-10-16T19:03:23.271Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyoig ConcurrencyTester JID-1ce4940b3400bb98a9be726f INFO: fail: 10.005 sec
2017-10-16T19:03:23.272Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyook ConcurrencyTester JID-bfd999897d7387cd01b909c0 INFO: fail: 10.007 sec
2017-10-16T19:03:23.272Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyouo ConcurrencyTester JID-03b860c995c6040d2de18707 INFO: fail: 10.006 sec
2017-10-16T19:03:23.273Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyp0s ConcurrencyTester JID-d313f82c66f973caaaaf5ea6 INFO: fail: 10.006 sec
2017-10-16T19:03:23.274Z 54312 TID-oxiqhyp6w ConcurrencyTester JID-e057dd6c641e9240250ca40a INFO: fail: 10.004 sec
```

When retries are enabled, the jobs will fail the first time, but after several attempts, one by one they will succeed. When the jobs are run one by one, they always succeed. When the concurrency of the workers is one (running them one at a time instead of the same time) they succeed. When the mutex is not present, they succeed. When the task doesn't involve the database, they succeed, and whatever the database query, they fail.

**Edit: raw SQL does not trigger this issue, which suggests Rails' Active Record may be the culprit. Still no solution as of now, however.**

**Same issue in Sidekiq issues, unresolved: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3359 and https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3415 . Demo here: https://github.com/chrisyuska/sidekiq-mutex-deadlock-demo**

Comment: What is `Admin`, what does the `count` method do? If `Admin` is a plain `ActiveRecord::Base`: Are there any default_scopes on `Admin` defined? How many records are there in the DB? What DB engine to your use? Is there an index on that table?

Comment: Admin is a model that corresponds to a mysql database table. Admin.count would normally return 24, since it's a nearly empty table, and it does so in other contexts in less than 1ms. I also tried simple queries like Product.first or User.find(1) and they all hang forever in the same way.

Comment: Can you test `Admin.count` in the context of your worker? Like `def test_count; Admin.count; end;` then run `ConcurrencyTester.new.test_count`

Comment: Okay! I tested that and the result was the same. It hung perpetually until the timeout triggered. Same even while using the debugger `byebug`.

Comment: Please use TTIN to debug lockups https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals#ttin